# Verifying the existence of a method

Tags: php

Is possible to verify the existence of a method without instantiating the class in php? How I do it?

I need to check in real time the existence of a method to build my links, but instantiate the classes is very expensive and unnecessary (don't need the classes at the time), so `is_callable` and `method_exists` are not an option.

Comment: If you need to verify the existence of a class method before it's instantiated, I would suspect that your workflow is not designed as well as it could be.

Comment: Thanks, @LeviMorrison. Maybe at the end of the day just caching the links, but this way of doing it's interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or [ReflectionClass::hasMethod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasmethod.php)

Comment: This is the correct answer ... I ca't implement it but that is the subject of another question. Thanks!

Comment: Instantiate an ReflectionClass Object with the Name of your Class (e.g. `$a = new ReflectionClass('My_Class');`. Then you can check the existence with `$a->hasMethod('myMethodName')`.

Comment: Thanks, @breiti... the problem [looks now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463693/reflectionclass-in-codeigniter-model) a little different