# ReflectionClass in Codeigniter Model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to verify the existence of a method in a controller from a model with codeigniter 2.0.2. and HMVC.

I'm trying to do with `ReflectionClass:hasMethod()`, without success.

My code in Model:

```
function hasPanel($controller){
    $rc = new ReflectionClass($controller);
    if($rc::hasMethod("panel_base")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the unwelcome error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class administracion does not exist' in D:\xampp\htdocs\sea\application\models\auth\permisos.php:368
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\sea\application\models\auth\permisos.php(368): ReflectionClass-&gt;__construct('administracion')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\sea\application\models\auth\permisos.php(357): Permisos-&gt;hasPanel('administracion')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\sea\application\controllers\auth\identificar.php(101): Permisos-&gt;getControladores('administracion')
#3 [internal function]: Identificar-&gt;modulo()
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\sea\application\core\Admin_controller.php(317): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\sea\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(305): Admin_controller-&gt;_remap('modulo', Array)
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\sea\www\index.php(252): require_once('D:\xampp\htdocs...')
#7 {main}
  thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\sea\application\models\auth\permisos.php on line 368
```

**EDITED**
This solves the above...

```
function hasPanel($controller,$route){
    include_once($route);
    $rc = new ReflectionClass($controller);
    if($rc::hasMethod("panel_base")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But causes this:

```
Fatal error: Non-static method ReflectionClass::hasMethod() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in D:\xampp\htdocs\sea\application\models\auth\permisos.php on line 373
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but this might be as simple as `$rc->hasMethod("panel_base")`;  You did instantiate a new class. . .

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$rc::hasMethod("panel_base")
```

to

```
$rc->hasMethod("panel_base")
```